# SQL Server XML replace value

Tags: sql-server, xml

XML noobie here  -  trying to get up to speed quickly for a one-time, adhoc data update on existing XML column in SQL Server 2008.  I have drafted the following test code to figure out the correct syntax:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML
SET @XMLData = '
<Parts>
  <Part>
    <ID>(548753,10300)</ID>
    <PartID>(1030,12014)</PartID>
    <CalculatedQuantity>233</CalculatedQuantity>
    <CalculatedCost>11.65</CalculatedCost>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <ID>(548752,10300)</ID>
    <PartID>(1001,12014)</PartID>
    <CalculatedQuantity>0.25</CalculatedQuantity>
    <CalculatedCost>5</CalculatedCost>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <ID>(548751,10300)</ID>
    <PartID>(1842,12014)</PartID>
    <CalculatedQuantity>0.25</CalculatedQuantity>
    <CalculatedCost>15</CalculatedCost>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <ID>(548750,10300)</ID>
    <PartID>(1929,12014)</PartID>
    <CalculatedQuantity>47.86</CalculatedQuantity>
    <CalculatedCost>27.2271577192</CalculatedCost>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <ID>(548749,10300)</ID>
    <PartID>(1973,12014)</PartID>
    <CalculatedQuantity>0.3</CalculatedQuantity>
    <CalculatedCost>2.829</CalculatedCost>
  </Part>
</Parts>
'
SET @XMLData.modify ('
    replace value of 
        (/Parts/Part[@PartID = "(1929,12014)"]/CalculatedQuantity/text())[1]

  with "6.5" ');
```

In case I am so far off that it is not even apparent, I am trying to update the value of CalculatedQuantity only in the nodes where PartID = som value.  However clearly I've got something wrong  -  nothing changes when I execute this -  and I can't find a good example to figure out what.   Eventually @PartID will equal sql:column as will the amount of the update.  But for now I just want to get the basic syntax working.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close -- in fact, you're only one character off. `@PartID` matches an attribute named "PartID", not an element. It should be this:

```
SET @XMLData.modify ('
    replace value of (/Parts/Part[PartID = "(1929,12014)"]/CalculatedQuantity/text())[1]
    with "6.5"
');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked a charm!   Sorry I'm such a beginner here that I can't upvote your answer.

Comment: @Susan: that's fine, we have a badge for everything here. Including [having a certain percentage of accepted answers with no upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious). :-)